# Temporarily unfreeze UI to allow a DOM update

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have some code that functions like so. It will iterate over an array with `forEach`, perform a heavy task that freezes the UI with the current iteration, push the returned value from that heavy task to an array, and then return the array being pushed to after the `forEach` has concluded. This is how it would work:

```js
// generate a dummy array
var array = Array.from(Array(1000000).keys()):

function doSomething() {
    // the array to push to
    var pushArray = [];

    array.forEach((item) => {
        // perform a heavy task...
        const output = doHeavyThing(item);

        // ...and push the heavy task result to an array
        pushArray.push(output);

        // (this DOM call will not work, because doHeavyThing blocks the UI)
        document.getElementById('updateDiv').innerHTML = item;
    })

    // return the array that was pushed to
    return pushArray;
}

const result = doSomething();
return result;
```

**Is there any way I can temporarily pause the execution of the `forEach` loop, unfreezing the UI, to allow for a DOM update?** This would only require a couple of milliseconds.

I cannot use web workers in this situation, because the data being returned is so large that any calls to `postMessage` would crash the browser on mobile.

I also haven't been able to get `setTimeout` to work, because it is asynchronous - meaning I cannot return anything. I also cannot reliably use callbacks.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem? Clarifying questions are always welcome.

My `doHeavyThing` function is a function from the [seek-bzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seek-bzip) package:

```js
bzip.decodeBlock(compressedDataBlock, 32);
```

Comment: Did you intend to return `pushArray`? If so, why seeing as it is global? Also the `output` you return does not exist in the current scope because it declared as const in an inner scope (`forEach`)

Comment: @smac89 you are correct. I did mean to return pushArray, and it will be initialized within doSomething(). Thanks for the catch, I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: If you can't use any asynchronous solutions (promises, callbacks), then your only answer is fully synchronous, which precludes updating the DOM. If you want to yield execution to the event loop, that is the definition of asynchrony in JS.

Comment: @CollinD I would be perfectly fine using async, I just don’t know how I would then be able to use return statements like I have outlined.

Comment: The problem is that depending on how heavy `doHeavyThing` actually is, it is not enough to convert your `doSomething` function to a promise i.e. making it async, you need to ensure that `doHeavyThing` yields some control to the event loop, so that the UI can still update while the work is going on. You can try observables, or use setTimeout within `doHeavyThing` to accomplish this. You can post `doHeavyThing` here if you want help accomplishing this

Comment: @smac89 I’ve updated my question to include the doHeavyThing function.

Comment: That library looks like it is meant for NodeJS. Are you doing this in Node or in the Browser?

Comment: @smac89 I am doing this in the browser, by bundling that and other libraries with Browserify.

Comment: You need to convert your code to asynchrnous - that means abandoning the idea of returning anything and instead work with callbacks and/or promises. You were on the right track with setTimeout - it's one of the few built-in functions that can make code asynchronous. I'm sorry to say it's the only way - forget about returning values.

Comment: It looks to me that the heavy work being done can't really be fixed unless the library provides a way to do this. I suggest de-compressing smaller chunks of data and combining these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this would work to ensure the event loop can tick in between calls to `doHeavyThing`.

```js
// create a promise that will resolve on the next tick of the event loop
function sleep() { 
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r));
}

// standin for doHeavyThing. This is enough to induce
// noticable delay on my machine, tweak the # of iterations
// if it's too fast to notice on yours
function doHeavyThing() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { console.log(i); }
}

async function handleHeavyLifting() {
    const array = Array.from(Array(1000).keys());
    const result = [];
    for (const item of array) {
      document.getElementById('updateDiv').innerHTML = item;
      result.push(doHeavyThing(item));
      // let DOM updates propagate, other JS callbacks run, etc
      await sleep();
    }
    return result;
}

handleHeavyLifting();
```

```html
<div id="updateDiv">
None
</div>
```

---

Comment: This looks great, but if I wanted to do something at the end like `const result = handleHeavyLifting();` and then `return result;` (because all of this code is in its own function), the return statement wouldn't work, as `handleHeavyLifting` returns a promise, and you cannot return inside of a `then` statement, e.g. `handleHeavyLifting().then((response) => { return response; })` would not work.

Comment: `return` is a synchronous construct. The async function returns a promise, which is a stand-in indicating that a value will be ready eventually. If you want to await that value, you'll need to make your consumer async or consume the promise using `.then`. You can't have it both ways (in terms of being synchronous AND asynchronous)

Comment: https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/ This is a great piece talking about the sometimes surprising nature of asynchronous functions in js

Comment: I got it to work using your `sleep` function - it does indeed allow a DOM update to happen. I had to rewrite all of the return statements into callbacks, but it wasn't that bad. Thanks again for the help!